# Angular JS changing the variable syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to change how Angular echos variables, after reading some tutorials I gather I need to:

> change the interpolation symbols in Laravel. Simply pass the $interpolateProvider to your app module, and set the tags you wish to use instead.

As I'm new to Angular I have no idea what that means. So I have the following:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

var app = angular.module('studious', function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});

</script>

<div ng-app="">
  <p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
  <h1>Hello [[name]]</h1>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You need to do this in your config function, the following should work:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

var app = angular.module('studious', []);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider){
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});

</script>

<div ng-app="studious">
<p>Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name"></p>
<h1>Hello [[name]]</h1>

</div>
```

[image: Working]

Answer (score 2):

Look at the example in the docs [`$interpolateProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider), you need to configure in the .config method:

```js
var customInterpolationApp = angular.module('customInterpolationApp', []);

customInterpolationApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
});


customInterpolationApp.controller('DemoController', function() {
  this.name = "Dale Snowdon";
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="customInterpolationApp" ng-controller="DemoController as demo">
  <p>Name:
    <input type="text" ng-model="demo.name">
  </p>
  <h1>Hello [[demo.name]]</h1>
</div>
```